# barcode39 generation in php

Tags: php, barcode

I have gone through this [link](http://www.shayanderson.com/php/php-barcode-generator-class-code-39.htm)  for the barcode generation.

I have downloaded the zip file and tested in my local host. It worked there, after that I have kept the files in my project and checked there. It doesn't work instead it gave me corrupted image as below.

GIF87aP���������,P���������p�قzu���b�a�I���xmZơFÌ,��}r�~���[�pH��(��>V�ie����q����dZΰ�+�����'�=]��n9?^wv�g��W���UƵ���h�8x(h�����GG� I��z�I:�j�y*zY�ij�::[� �Z+p+�J�k�Z�K�k�|��L�)����`N���qt���r���"�P���>�NA<~��]�p��{���!D +Z�ؠ;

Now I've created a sample file in the same location in my project with simple `<?php ?>` tags and kept the code

```
include "Barcode39.php"; 

// set Barcode39 object 
$bc = new Barcode39("abc"); 

// display new barcode 
$bc->draw();
```

again it worked in the sample file which I have kept in the project, but it is not working in the project related file.

Not getting the issue here.

Comment: Could you post the code in the project related file?

Comment: check if you are sending any other output? if you are using a browser and also check you are sending proper headers.

Comment: I kept the same code (3 line code)which I have mentioned above.

Comment: Where are you putting your include in your project? And are you already using the variable?

Comment: Not sure if this is a corrupted image. May be just a missing header to display image properly ?

Comment: @Nagendra are you using any framework?

Comment: it's a core php and I've mentioned the header as header("Content-type: image/gif");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its perfectly working fine, make sure Barcode39.php in the same location.
As well it required PHP:GD, check again its install or not.
(Include could be issue if you are using any other framework)
I tested and got the below output 
[image]

You can also use the below code to generate the gif file of barcode and link it anywhere in any page. you will not face any issue related to using html tags.

```
<?
// include Barcode39 class 
include "Barcode39.php"; 
// set object 
$bc = new Barcode39("123-ABC"); 

// set text size 
$bc->barcode_text_size = 5; 

// set barcode bar thickness (thick bars) 
$bc->barcode_bar_thick = 4; 

// set barcode bar thickness (thin bars) 
$bc->barcode_bar_thin = 2; 

// save barcode GIF file 
$bc->draw("barcode1.gif");

?>
```

and include this file in the src attr of the image tag like

```
<img src="http://localhost/yourbarcodefilepath" alt="barcode"/>
```

then it will work

Comment: even it is working fine in my localhost, but the thing is it is creating some issue when I place that in my project folder.

Comment: Project folder means you are trying to deploy the php in linux box where your website running??

Comment: when I try the <html></body> tags in the sample file, it doesn't work.

Comment: Got it I also tried its not working if I am surrounding the barcdoe with HTML BODY tag. Write the code in one php without html and body and then incude your sample.php and Barcode39.php in other php where you want html and body

Comment: @Nagendra you are saying image generation code is not working or incuding in thirf php is not working??I edited my answer for image generation which must have to work without any issue.As I tested multiple time. For more details join the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59264/discussion-between-prashant-thakre-and-nagendra).